# PHP PECL Gnupg extension takes more time

Tags: php, encryption, load-testing, gnupg

I have implemented the PECL extension [gnupg](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gnupg.php) **(pecl.php.net/gnupg-1.3.6
)** for password encryption and decryption in my project.

During a load test of 500 + users the methods $this->gnu->setarmor(0); and  $this->gnu->adddecryptkey() consumes more time than the other PHP processings.

Ex: If an average login time takes 10 secs, the processing time for the gnupg alone takes 5 to 6 secs.

Just wondering why the gnupg alone takes more time during a load test.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I've voted to close this as "too broad". Without seeing the code and/or further profiling performed by you, it's hardly possible providing any reasonable response to your issue.

Comment: It's unusual practice to encrypt passwords in such a way that they can be decrypted. It would be more typical to use a password hashing function such as [`password_hash`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) (or, before PHP 5.5, [`crypt`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php)) and verify the password using [`password_verify`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) (or by calling `crypt` again and comparing the hashes).

Comment: The functionality was implemented long back ago may be in 2008 and the sad thing is I am new to this project. During a load test of 500+ users in Jmeter this Gnupg alone consumes more time and since gnupg is a PECL extension i didnt add any source code in this thread the only fucntiona i am calling is $this->gnu->setarmor(0); and $this->gnu->adddecryptkey().

Answer (score 0):

> I have implemented the PECL extension gnupg (pecl.php.net/gnupg-1.3.6 ) for password encryption and decryption in my project.

Why not just use [the *password hashing* features](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.password.php) that PHP ships with? [Encryption is not the right tool for the "password storage" job](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/08/you-wouldnt-base64-a-password-cryptography-decoded).